# Yearling badge awarded multiple times today

Tags: bug, badges

I'm getting some odd behavior on the site today, it's awarded me the yearling badge 5 times over and keeps doing so every hour or so, perhaps in response to some actions I'm taking, but I can't tell for sure.

[image: way too many yearling badges]

[image: earned this badge 5 times (all today)]

Comment: Your profile says you're a "*Member for 6 years, 8 months*". Maybe those 5 badges were overdue and the system is now compensating? (just a hypothesis)

Comment: Did you earn most of your rep in the past year?